# Git Squash commits from mysqldump

Tags: git, shell, mysql

I'm using the following script to backup a database with Git. The backup.sql file is +- 5 MB. Now after some months the repository is getting pretty big (325 MB).

I presume Git is saving the backup.sql file multiple times (not just the changes), so I would like to remove some commits, so the corresponding versions of the backup.sql file get deleted.

Now I've read about squashing commits, But all those examples are about squashing the last commits into 1 commit.

How can I squash the commits so I have like 1 commit for each month and all commits for the last month, this so the size of the repository is under the 50 MB?

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/exampleUser/sites/example.com/backup

NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")

/usr/local/bin/mysqldump exampleDatabase -p3306 -hexample.com -uexampleMysqlUser -pexamplePassword > backup.sql

/usr/local/bin/git add -A
/usr/local/bin/git commit -m "Auto backup ${NOW}"
/usr/local/bin/git push
```

Comment: Maybe you should just investigate a backup script that save your SQL dumps to files?  You're not really getting any benefit from using git in this case.

Comment: The reason was so I could easily go to an older version of the mysqldump using git commands.

Comment: And if you were saving dumps to files that included a timestamp you could do the same thing, *and* you could use something as simple as `find -mtime ...` to delete old backups.

Comment: That would be a possible alternative. But I would like to solve it using git so I can push it to a git server where the code of the application is also stored.